# How should I do certain things according to ANSI SQL (AUTO_INCREMENT, TEXT, VARCHAR etc)

Tags: sql

I want to know how certain things should look like in ANSI SQL to write expressions which will as much standard-accepted as possible.

For example,

- Where should I place `PRIMARY KEY`, `UNIQUE` and all other special words like these? Should I place it right after the column type (e.g. `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`) or should I place it after all columns (e.g. `id INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (id)`)?
- How should I insert rows to the tables which contains `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns? Should I pass `NULL` to these columns (e.g. `INSERT INTO foo VALUES(NULL,1,2)`) or should I just omit these columns names before `VALUES` part of expression (e.g. `INSERT INTO foo (bar,baz) VALUES(1,2)`)?
- Is there any rule in ANSI SQL about whitespace characters? Should I always place it after `VALUES` word, for example? Or should I place whitespace characters between columns names or parameters (e.g. `INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz) VALUES(1, 2)`)?
- Which characters according to ANSI SQL should I use to escape tables and columns names (e.g. `)?
- Is `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature fully standard?
- Which types defined by ANSI SQL? For example, is `TEXT` type defined in standard?
- Is there any limitations about the max. size of `VARCHAR` column?
- Is `PRIMARY KEY` automatically `NOT NULL` according to ANSI SQL?

Comment: Great questions, but this is not the right place for them. Some quick answers: pk not null, ", sequences. No. Yes.

Comment: @jarlh Which answers related to which questions?

Comment: [ANSI'92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt).

Comment: ANSI standards have their place, but the answers to your questions probably depend on your database engine.

Answer (score 1):

> Where should I place PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE and all other special words like these

This mainly depends on personal preference. But e.g. for multi-column primary keys, the only place where you can put the PK definition is at the end:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table
(
  col_one integer not null, 
  col_two integer not null,
  primary key (col_one, col_two)
);
```

You can't define such a PK when you put the `primary key` right after the column(s). The same obviously is true for unique and foreign key constraints.

---

> Is PRIMARY KEY automatically NOT NULL according to ANSI SQL

The column is not automatically defined as `NOT NULL` but PK columns are *required* to be `NOT NULL`: "*In addition, if the unique constraint was defined with PRIMARY KEY, then it requires that none of the values in the specified column or columns be a null value*"

---

> Which characters according to ANSI SQL should I use to escape tables and columns names

The only character to escape non-standard names is the double quote `"`, e.g. `"Foo Bar"`. Note that in the standard this also makes the name case **sensitive**. `"foobar"` and `"FooBar"` are two different names in the SQL standard.

---

> Is AUTO_INCREMENT feature fully standard

No, it's completely non-standard. The standard would be `integer not null generated always as identity` (if I'm not mistaken)

---

> How should I insert rows to the tables which contains AUTO_INCREMENT columns? Should I pass NULL to these columns

No. If you pass `NULL` you state that you intend to store a `NULL` value. To let the DBMS apply the default you either leave out the column completely, e.g. `INSERT INTO foo (col1, col2) VALUES (1,2)` or use the keyword `default`: `insert into foo (pk_col, col1, col2) values (default, 4, 2)`

---

> Is there any rule in ANSI SQL about whitespace characters

No, there isn't

---

> Which types defined by ANSI SQL?

The data types defined by the standard are:

- CHARACTER
- CHARACTER VARYING
- CHARACTER LARGE OBJECT
- BINARY
- BINARY VARYING
- BINARY LARGE OBJECT
- NUMERIC
- DECIMAL
- SMALLINT
- INTEGER
- BIGINT
- FLOAT
- REAL
- DOUBLE PRECISION
- BOOLEAN
- DATE
- TIME
- TIMESTAMP
- INTERVAL

---

> For example, is TEXT type defined in standard?

No, it isn't

---

> Is there any limitations about the max. size of VARCHAR column?

I can't find an explicit limitatation. The only thing I can find after a quick search is: "*A character string has a length, which is the number of characters in the sequence. The length is 0 (zero) or a positive integer*". So whatever limit it has it is defined by the maximum value of an integer. The standard uses the term "integer" to identify whole numbers (without a decimal digits) but as far as I can tell it does not specify a maximum value for them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What about the other questions btw?

Answer (score 1):

Is PRIMARY KEY automatically NOT NULL according to ANSI SQL?

> Yes. Non nullable and uniqueness contraints are implied

Is there any limitations about the max. size of VARCHAR column?

> VARCHAR(8000) uses normal data pages till 8K for any size beyond 8K, for example varchar(max) which can store 2^31 -1 characters will be stored as TEXT, IMAGE etc

Comment: There is nothing in the SQL standard about `varchar(8000)` - actually the standard does not define the type name `varchar` at all.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What should I use instead of `VARCHAR` type then? `CHARACTER VARYING`?